# Is it idiomatic or colloquial to say "space the washing so they can dry faster"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Some people hang out their washing in such a way that there is not much space between the clothes, which take them longer to get dry.

Is it idiomatic or colloquial to say "**space the washing so they can dry faster**"?

Comment: Prefer **space it out**.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93224/what-does-space-it-out-mean

Comment: I would probably say _spread it out [more]_ (_washing_ is a collective noun when referring to laundry).